# IntelliJ not launching due to missing plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I downloaded a plugin from here: [I-Pascal](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7340-i-pascal/versions) for a new project I wanted to make in Pascal language on my IntelliJ IDEA.

After I downloaded the Pascal plugin zip file, I extracted it and then opened a new maven project in IntelliJ and did "Add plugin from Disk" and then clicked "Restart IDEA".

IntelliJ IDEA closed without reopening, and until now every time I try to launch IntelliJ it won't launch and it shows me a "Start Failed" dialog telling me the plugin not found:

> com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.siberika.idea.pascal.PascalAppService' [Plugin: com.siberika.idea.pascal]
> at....
> .
> .
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/siberika/idea/pascal/PascalException...
> .
> .
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.siberika.idea.pascal.PascalException

I'm using IntelliJ 2022.3.1 on windows 10 and the last pascal plugin version(2.80)

I tried reinstalling the plugin or opening the IntelliJ on safe mode using the 'idea.bat' command it still gave me the same error. The error dialog suggests looking for a solution here: [IntelliJ critical startup error](https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors) .
But I couldn't find something that could help me.

And now I can't keep going with my project!! Does someone face the same problem before ??

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck all the plugins that were giving the errors in the settings -> plugins menu, then restart IntelliJ IDEA and enable them back

Another possible solution is to delete the latest plugin that you installed in the IntelliJ plugins directory and reinstall it.

Comment: I can't reach the settings -> plugins menu because I can't launch IntelliJ IDEA,
and I did delete and reinstalled the plugin and I still got the same "Start Fail" dialog

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the offending plug-in from the [Plugins directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory).

Comment: I did it and still got the same "Start Fail" dialog

Comment: What plug-in did you remove and from what directory? Please share the full log file. It's better to contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new and attach all the logs to the ticket.

Comment: I reinstall the pascal plugin that probably causing that problem.

Comment: Thank you bro but I somehow managed to launch it !! It's so weird ?!!!

Comment: I deleted the directory plugins and worked. `rm -rf plugin`